# Prevent certain subscribers from seeing specific taxonomies (changes frequently)

Tags: taxonomy, users, content-restriction

I've created a taxonomy (let's call it `tax`). I need to limit what a user can see. The users can't edit anything, just read the blog. If it was just setting what they could see once, I'd probably just create a new user role, but what they will be viewing will change frequently.

So for an example:

```
   user1 can view tax1, tax4
   user2 can view tax3
   user3 can view tax1, tax2
```

Then next week that all changes (kinda like checking out a movie or a book then returning it).
How can a make sure that the users can't view any other taxonomies than the ones they're assigned?
I'm hoping there is a function that I just haven't found that is something like:

```
if(!get_taxonomy(ID)){
    echo "You're not permitted to view this";
}else{
    //Continue with showing page...
}
```

I already have things set up so that in their user profiles I can assign them their taxonomies. So on the frontend when the page pulls up I can check which taxonomies they can see. But they can still navigate to other taxonomies. If they see that they're on `http://website/tax1/` then they could just type in `http://website/tax2/` and see the other taxonomies.
This has to be done on an individual user basis and not assigned to a role since there will be so many different users and so many different taxonomies.
Sorry I can't provide a live example; it's being developed locally and it contains some sensitive info.
If I need to clarify anything I'm more than happy to. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you storing what users can view what taxonomies? Usermeta?

Comment: Yes, through usermeta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like `if( in_array( $current_tax, get_user_meta( $user, 'legal_taxonomies', true ) ) )` You can get the current taxonomy information using [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by). This operates on the assumption that you're storing the available taxonomies as an array, but is easily changed for any storage method.

Comment: Dude! You are my hero! I've been battling this for hours. I had to modify things just a bit to get it working, but it's your answer that got me going down the correct path. Here's what I went with: `$slug = $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'];
$value = get_term_by('slug', $slug, 'taxonomy')->term_id;
$a_terr = get_user_meta( $user, 'user-meta', true );` and then the check: `if(!in_array($value,$a_terr)){//kick them out<br/>}else{}`. Again, thank you!